# How to properly tie a hash with DBM::Deep to avoid memory leaks?

Tags: perl, dbm

I am doing a graph analysis of some very large data and I need to store all the scores for a particular set of graph edges. Given the size of the data, I need to write the information to disk and I'm trying to use a tied hash with [DBM::Deep](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/DBM-Deep/lib/DBM/Deep.pod). Here is the basic set up:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
use File::Spec;
use DBM::Deep;
use Cwd;

my $file = shift;
my $wd = getcwd();

open my $fh, '<', $file;

my %match_pairs;
my $dbm = File::Spec->catfile($wd, "pairs.dbm");
unlink $dbm if -e $dbm;

tie %match_pairs, 'DBM::Deep', { 
    file      => $dbm, 
    locking   => 1, 
    autoflush => 1, 
    type      => DBM::Deep::TYPE_HASH 
};
```

Then, I parse the file and store the information above a certain score threshold like so (`$pair` is just a regular string):

```
if (exists $match_pairs{$pair}) {
    push @{$match_pairs{$pair}}, $score;
}
else {
    $match_pairs{$pair} = [$score];
}
```

This code produces a memory leak that will increase until you kill the process. If I comment out these six lines, no memory leak. The odd thing is that the data is written to the DBM file, and I get the same result when I am using DBM::Deep or not, so it seems like the tie method is correct. I've changed the journal mode, autoflush, locking, and other settings and I see the same behavior.

Am I using DBM::Deep incorrectly here? For example, should I be using the OO interface or is there a better way to code this method?

I will preemptively say that it is hard to provide an example file to reproduce this issue because the script needs to be running a few seconds for the leak to be noticed (meaning the file has to be at least 100k lines). My hope is that something will jump out, but I will provide a script and some data if this is not enough information. I'm using Perl v5.20.2 and the latest DBM::Deep, 2.0011.

EDIT: I have simplified the code to:

```
$match_pairs{$pair} = $score;
```

and I have also tried the OO interface doing a simple key/value store and I see the same behavior. It seems like this must be a bug so I will report it.

Comment: Utterly unrelated to your problem, but you can probably remove lines all but the `push` line there and get the same result.

Comment: @JimDavis I read that autovivication does not work properly with DBM::Deep, or used to not anyway, so I am using the `if (exists $hash{key}) { ... }` syntax to be safe.

Comment: I didn't know that.  Oh, well!

Comment: I am able to reproduce this with even simpler code. Switching from directly accessing the hash to using the returned DBM::Deep object cuts the run-time of my test script from several minutes to under a second: `my $db = tie %hash, 'DBM::Deep', '/path/to/file'; $db->{foo} = 'bar';` instead of `$hash{foo} = 'bar';` Memory usage didn't change drastically in my test, but it seems clear that direct hash accesses are not optimized.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: The value returned by `tie` is just an object that has methods to manipulate the database as if it were a hash, and the tied hash is just a medium to call those methods. So manipulating your `$db` just puts spurious data into an in-memory object and doesn't touch the database; that's why it's so much quicker. You could use `$db->STORE($key, $val)` if you wanted, but its simplest to use the tied variable and write `$hash{$key} = $val`. By the way, disabling `locking` and `autoflush` speeds things up significantly too, as you'd expect.

Comment: @Borodin Ah, I see that now. I was confused by the bit in the docs that says, "Because *all DBM::Deep objects* are tied to hashes or arrays, you can treat them as such...DBM::Deep will intercept all reads/writes and direct them to the right place -- the DB file." and the examples that follow. I assumed this also meant those returned by `tie`. Any thoughts on the memory usage?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: Yes the docs are pretty poor. The way it works is that the OO interface does a `tie` internally and returns a reference to the tied hash, which you *can* use directly.  And no, not really, although I can see that the process has 1,000 extra scalar variables for every 1,000 pushes onto the hash, but I have no idea why

Comment: I reported this issue on github and to the CPAN bug tracker. It appears there was already a [bug report](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=94291) and discussion on the google groups site from a year ago with no resolution. Here is a [link](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=103795) to the bug report with a simple example. Similar to the other report, I found no memory cycles but there is clearly a leak somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I answered this in the associated GH issue (thank you for opening it!), but I'll repeat it here.

Yes, the amount of RAM does slowly uptick over time. When reading `/usr/dict/words` as keys into a DBM::Deep hash (Ubuntu 14.04, Perl 5.22.0), my RAM upticked by about 1k for every 30k words read. My guess (without a repeatable test) is that this is just the bookkeeping DBM::Deep needs to track the additional levels of data that adding 30k elements requires.

As I mentioned in my comment in the issue, I'd be delighted to work on this further if there's a repeatable testfile I can commit to the project.